# can light bounce off another light?

Tags: particle-physics, visible-light, waves, wave-particle-duality

If light is a wave and a particle (wave particle duality), is it possible for light to  bounce off another light since light bounces of another matter(particle)?

Comment: Maybe this previous post might be useful: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28551/can-electrons-change-the-frequency-of-light-as-they-bounce-off-around    AFAIK, you treat light and elementary particles as either particles or waves, depending on which measurement you perform, not both particles and waves simultaneously.